Last table row in the page is hidden
In the following example I have 25 rows. The document is divided into 2 pages. The first page contains rows from 1 to 13 while the second page contains pages from 15 to 25. As you can notice row number 14 is hidden. How to solve this issue?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">

<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pagedjs/dist/paged.polyfill.js"></script>

<style>

#header {
    position: running(runningHeader);
    background-color: lightgray;
    height: 30mm;
    margin-top: 25.4mm;
    margin-bottom: 2.5mm;
    border: 0.25mm solid black;
}

#footer {
    position: running(runningFooter);
    background-color: lightgray;
    height: 20mm;
    margin-bottom: 25.4mm;
    margin-top: 2.5mm;
    border: 0.25mm solid black;
}

.content {
    background: orange;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


@media print {

    @page {

        size: A4;
        margin-top: 57.9mm;
        margin-bottom: 47.9mm;
        margin-left: 25.4mm;
        margin-right: 25.4mm;

        @top-center {
            content: element(runningHeader);
            background: yellow;
        }

        @bottom-center {
            content: element(runningFooter);
            background: yellow;
        }

        .currentPageNumber::before{
            content: counter(page)
        }

        .totalNumberOfPages::before{
            content: counter(pages)
        }

    }

}

h3, p {
    margin: 0mm;
    padding: 0mm;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  border: 0.25mm solid black;
  padding: 1mm;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <header id="header">
        <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
            <div>
                <h1>Header goes here</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <footer id="footer">
        <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
            <div>
                <div>
                    Page <span class="currentPageNumber"></span> of <span class="totalNumberOfPages"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <div class="content">
        <h3 style="text-align: center; padding: 1mm; text-decoration: underline;">The Title of the Report</h3>
        <div style="text-align: center; padding: 1mm;">
            <span style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">Date:</span> 2024-09-04
            <span style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">Time:</span> 14:20:31
        </div>
        <table>
            <thead style="background-color: lightgray;">
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Valid Until</th>
                    <th>Entry Date</th>
                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                    <th>Reference Number</th>
                    <th>Note</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>8</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>11</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>12</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>13</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>15</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>16</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>17</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>18</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>19</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>20</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>21</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>24</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>25</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04</td>
                    <td>2024-09-04 13:15:14</td>
                    <td>Company</td>
                    <td>115.00</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>

</body>

</html>

